# Does yum use package buildtime to decide if a package is newer?

Tags: yum, rpm

Say I have installed `mypkg-1.2.3-4567.noarch.rpm` from some yum repo.

1. Is it valid for the rpm publisher to re-publish mypkg with the *same* version and release and just run `createrepo --update`? Is it recommended?
2. If #1 is allowed, will yum upgrade my installation of mypkg if I run yum install mypkg again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the rpm publisher has to increase the release number each time the rpm changes. `yum update mypkg` or `yum install mypkg` will have no effect if a package with the same name-version-release is already installed.

Comment: thank you. I searched but could not find this assertion in the yum man page or other official documentation. Could you please point me to something official that says this?